# Error in sonarqube configuration using command prompt

Tags: sonarlint, sonarqube5.1, sonarlint-eclipse, sonarlint-vs, sonarlint-intellij

wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
jvm 1    | Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
jvm 1    | Unrecognized option: --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note the jdk path and that in sonarqube config file
then open command prompt and add ----------Sonarstart

Comment: Care to elaborate on your answer. Do you have a fix for GNU/Linux to?